# Javascript in google sheets: passing arguments that are ranges of cells to a function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to run & test this function in Google Sheets:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('NN');
var range_p = sheet.getRange('B32:J32');
var range_q = sheet.getRange('B33:J33');
kl_divergence(range_p, range_q);

function kl_divergence(range_p, range_q) {
  var norm = 0.00001;
  var i;
  var tot = 0.0;
  for (i = 0; i < range_p.length; i++){
    tot += range_p[i] * LOG((range_p[i] + norm) / (range_q[i] + norm));
  }
  return tot;
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 11, file "Code"
```

What's going on, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `getRange` returns the range object. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) I think that the reason of your issue is this. In your case, I think that `getValues()` is required to be used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) But from your script, I couldn't understand what you want to do in the for loop. So I cannot propose the modified script. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Thank you!  I'm trying to compute the Kullback-Liebler divergence of the two ranges (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)

Comment: Can you provide the script of `LOG()`?

Comment: sorry; that's supposed to be Math.log - the logarithmic function.  Here's a copy of my sheet so far: I was trying to see how hard it was to implement a feed-forward neural network in Google Sheets.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1seHFS847g16T8vN75EwASFL7UiI4wUcWmNkb3VN2zUs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. I think that each range of "B32:J32" and "B33:J33" are one row. So in your script, the modification of `sheet.getRange(###).getValues()[0]` is suitable. But when I saw your Spreadsheet, "B32:J32" and "B33:J33" are `0` and `#DIV/0!`, respectively. I think that this is also one of the issues. How about this?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the issue, but I figured out how to iterate over a series of cells without Javascript, so I think I should be good to go!  Still no idea why the undefined length thing keeps coming up though.

Comment: Can you provide your current script? If you can do, please add it to your question.

Comment: ```=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(B43:J43) * LOG((VALUE(B43:J43) + 0.001) / (VALUE(B45:J45) + 0.001))))```

Comment: Could please describe the steps you're taking to run the `kl_divergence` function?

Answer (score 0):

the `getRange()` function you are using returns a Range class https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.

I think you need to change it to:

```
var range_p = sheet.getRange('B32:J32').getValues();
var range_q = sheet.getRange('B33:J33').getValues();
```

Comment: I tried adding getValues() and it still threw the same error, alas.